# Node/JS: weird nested callback function

Tags: node.js, callback

I came across this callback function, `callbackPrinter`, and its usage in a Node.js project I'm working on. Not sure what it's doing, specifically in reference to `cb.apply(cb, arguments)`.

I'm having a hard time wrapping around my head what the whole `callbackPrinter` is doing. Can it be simplified? What is it doing other than logging the message?

Usage:

```
function someFunction(callback) {
  ...
  async.parallel([
    // Some stuff
  ], callbackPrinter(message, callback))
  ...
}
```

Function:

```
function callbackPrinter (message, cb) {
  return function (err) {
    if (err) { return cb.apply(cb, arguments) }

    // Some code to log message

    cb.apply(cb, arguments)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is an array, `cb` is `this`

The `apply()` method calls a function with a given `this` value, and `arguments` provided as an array (or an array-like object).

re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

So it is in there twice, the first one conditionally returns the callback, the second does stuff then the callback gets the `apply` which calls it there.

NOTE The `arguments` object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function. from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments  SO since the `.apply()` accepts that array-like object that works.

Answer (score 0):

The `callbackPrinter` function takes an [error-first callback function](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) and returns a new function which wraps the original and that additionally logs the given `message` if the callback is called without an `err`.

Can it be simplified? Possibly if the version of Node.js you are using is new enough. (And if the callbacks in your codebase are not weirdly making use of `this` being a reference to the currently executing function—passing `cb` as the first argument of `Function.apply()` is odd, typically you’d pass `undefined`.) Here’s a quick stab at it:

```
function callbackPrinter (message, cb) {
  return (err, ...args) => {
    if (!err) {
      // log message…
    }
    return cb(err, ...args)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Very often case the `.apply` be used, is you are not sure the exactly arguments struct/count in run-time. In your case, you are not sure weather it will have `err`.
2. Help you understand your code:

   1. when `async.parallel` is call, `callbackPrinter` run and return the function(`function (err) {..}`), the returned function will bind with the `finish/resolve trigger` of `async.parallel` .
   2. when all the works(`[ // Some stuff ]`) in `async.parallel` is run over(`finished/resolved/rejected`), the returned function will be called.
3. Easy way:

   ```js
   const message = require('message');
   const async = require('async');

   function someFunction(callback) {
         ...
         async.parallel([
           // Some stuff
         ], function(err){
             if (err) { return cb.apply(cb, arguments) }

             // Some code to log message

             cb.apply(cb, arguments)
         })
         ...
   }
   ```